# Check that the sets of points in $\mathbb R^3$ span the same affine subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry

> Check that the sets of points $\{(1, 1, 0) , (2, 1, 0) , (3, 1, 1)\}$ and $\{(2, 1, 0) , (3, 1 , 0) , (3, 1, 1)\}$ span in $\mathbb R^3$ the same affine subspace.

**My try:**
Consider the difference vectors of these sets.
For the first set: $(3,1,1)-(1,1,0)=(2,0,1), (2,1,0)-(1,1, 0)=(1,0,0)$
For the second set: $(3,1,1)-(2,1,0)=(1,0,1), (3,1,0)-(2,1,0)=(1,0,0) )$

It seems to me that since $(2,0,1)\neq (1,0,1)$ then these spaces span other parallelograms in an affine space and cannot span the same space, but I can't professionally justify it.

Comment: For the first set, you should compute $(1,1,0) - (2,1,0)$ and $(3,1,1) - (2,1,0)$ and the second set $(3, 1, 0) - (2, 1, 0) $ and $(3, 1, 1) - (2,1,0) $ . For the first set you will get $(-1, 0, 0)$ and $(1, 0, 1) $ and for the second set, you will get $(1, 0, 0)$ and $(1, 0, 1)$.  Now it is clear that the span is the same for both sets.

Comment: @MoneyManagementSkills I understand that in order to compare the span of vectors, I have to subtract the same vector from both sets for the reasoning to make sense?

Comment: @MoneyManagementSkills Moreover, considering the difference vectors of an affine space, the conclusion is to check whether these difference vectors span the same linear space?

Comment: Yes.  That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Refer to the book by David C Lay's linear algebra on section $1.4$ theorem $4$, the matrix $A =\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3\\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ can be row reduced in just one step so that the row echelon form has a pivot position in every row. The same is true for the other set. Also, you want to treat each point of your set as a vector and not point.

Answer (score 0):

*$Hint:$* The answer is positive if $(3,1,0)=c_1(1,1,0)+c_2(2,1,0)+c_3(3,1,1)$ holds for some real constants $c_i, (i=1,2,3).$

Comment: Will it be enough? I think it should also happen $(1,1,0)=d_1(2, 1, 0)+d_2(3, 1 , 0)+d_3(3, 1, 1)$ and $c_1+c_2+c_3=d_1+d_2+d_3=1$

Comment: Yes.. Absolutely correct.